# Serialport Readline Issue

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I have an app (vb.net) that has worked reliably for 12 years - but has started to give error messages.

I calculate rotation values - send them to the servo - then check to see if the transmission is complete.

The issue is that readline give me a timeout error

Here is the code -

```
Sub SendSerialData()
    CurrentPositionDisplay.BackColor = Color.White
    CameraServoReadOK = 0
    ' Send strings to CameraServo serial port.
    ServoCommdataOut = ServoCommdataOut & vbCr
    CameraServoComm.DiscardOutBuffer()
    CameraServoComm.ReadTimeout = 150
    CameraServoComm.Write(ServoCommdataOut)
    CameraServoReadOK = 0
    If VerboseLogging = 2 Then
        dtString = dispDt.ToString(datePatt)
        outMessage = dtString & " - " & ServoCommdataOut
        Call WriteToLog(outLabel, outMessage)
    End If

    If outLabel = "Starting Picture Sequence " Then
        SkipRead = True
    End If

    'wait code added to accomodate 5ms turnarround time at CameraServo
    Call DelayTimer(10)
    ' If SkipRead = False Then
    If SkipRead = False Then
        Try
            CameraServoCommDataIn = CameraServoComm.ReadLine()
        Catch ex As Exception
            outMessage = "Missed Read after servo write" & ex.ToString
            Call WriteToLog(outLabel, outMessage)
        End Try
        CameraServoReadOK = InStr(CameraServoCommDataIn, CameraServoresponseStartString, CompareMethod.Text)
        If CameraServoReadOK > 0 Then
            CameraServoStatusDataIn = CameraServoCommDataIn
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: check port is open or not before readline ` if cameraServoComm.IsOpen then CameraServoCommDataIn = CameraServoComm.ReadLine() Else   Call WriteToLog(outLabel, "Port is Closed .. ") End if `

Comment: Hi - issue solved but still confused - The solution was to move to a different USB3 connector on the motherboard. No receive timeouts. However with the old port I was able to send and receive using a terminal emulator with no errors. I'll try the suggested  open test now that I know I can get back to no errors with the USB move.